# SecurityException: Permission Denial on reading file from Downloads

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

There are some similar questions on StackOverflow but the situations they happened a little bit different.

I need to read a file (in Service) that user shared with a standard share mechanism.
There are no problems reading files from gallery or files shared by File Managers or Google Drive. But there are problems when I try to share files from Downloads.

I receive:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider
>   com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider from
>   ProcessRecord{432abf50 8550:clipboard.clipboardtest/u0a167} (pid=8550,
>   uid=10167) requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or
>   android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="virtualclipboard.copytodesktop"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER_ADVANCED" />

    <application>
        ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The code to read a file. I receive Uri in intent while share operation.

```
InputStream input = getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);
byte[] fileData = Converter.InputStreamToByteArray(input);

// ...

public class Converter {
    public static byte[] InputStreamToByteArray(InputStream inputStream) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int reads = inputStream.read();
            while(reads != -1){
                baos.write(reads);
                reads = inputStream.read();
            }
            return baos.toByteArray();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Reproduced on Nexus 5, 4.4.4, KitKat.

Comment: "I receive Uri in intent while share operation" -- from what? The Downloads app? Something else? You can get rid of the `MANAGE_DOCUMENTS` permission from your manifest, as that is a `signature`-level permission, which you cannot hold unless your app is part of a firmware build. Also, reading an entire file into memory, particularly using that method, will only succeed for small files, as you do not have that much heap space. I encourage you to find a solution that does not involve reading the entire file into memory.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about Downloads application. And yes, I can read file part by part not using much memory, but I need to be able to open it for reading at least.

Comment: Well, K-9 Mail had no problem using a PDF file I shared from the Downloads app on a Nexus 4 running Android 5.0. Have you validated what `fileUri` looks like? Also, you can get rid of all your download-related permissions, as they are all `signature` or `signature|system`, which you cannot hold.

Comment: Uri looks ok, as it looks by sharing with other applications (for example –`content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1081`). I've removed permissions you said and it doesn't helped. Also some applications (not all) can share files from Downloads app, so I'm doing something wrong. By the way I can share ".txt" files from Downloads app but can't share other types.